# Existence of least squares solution to $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does a least squares solution to $Ax=b$ always exist?

Comment: Relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Linear_least-squares (P.S. I didn't vote.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what is written on wiki. So, is the answer affirmative or not?

Comment: Quoting the Wikipedia page: "The pseudoinverse solves the least-squares problem as follows..."

Comment: I find this video is quite helpful for this question [Least squares approximation-Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/alternate-bases/orthogonal-projections/v/linear-algebra-least-squares-approximation)

Answer (score 11):

If you think at the least squares problem geometrically, the answer is obviously "yes", by definition.

Let me try to explain why. For the sake of simplicity, assume the number of rows of $A$ is greater or equal than the number of its columns and it has full rang (i.e., its columns are linearly independent vectors). Without these hypotheses the answer is still "yes", but the explanation is a little bit more involved.

If you have a system of linear equations

$$
Ax = b \ ,
$$

you can look at it as the following equivalent problem: does the vector $b$ belong to the span of the columns of $A$? That is,

$$
Ax = b \qquad \Longleftrightarrow \qquad \exists \ x_1, \dots , x_n \quad \text{such that }\quad x_1a_1 + \dots + x_na_n = b \ .
$$

Here, $a_1, \dots , a_n$ are the columns of $A$ and $x = (x_1, \dots , x_n)^t$. If the answer is "yes", then the system has a solution. Otherwise, it hasn't.

So, in this latter case, when $b\notin \mathrm{span }(a_1, \dots , a_n)$, that is, when your system **hasn't** a solution, you "change" your original system for another one which **by definition** has a solution. Namely, you change vector $b$ for the *nearest* vector $b' \in \mathrm{span }(a_1, \dots , a_n)$. This nearest vector $b'$ is the orthogonal projection of $b$ onto $\mathrm{span }(a_1, \dots , a_n)$. So the least squares solution to your system is, by definition, the solution of

$$
Ax = b' \ ,  \qquad\qquad\qquad   (1)
$$

and your original system, with this change and the aforementioned hypotheses, becomes

$$
A^t A x = A^tb  \ . \qquad\qquad\qquad    (2)
$$

EDIT. Formula (1) becomes formula (2) taking into account that the matrix of the orthogonal projection onto the span of columns of $A$ is

$$
P_A = A(A^tA)^{-1}A^t \ .
$$

(See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Orthogonal_projections).)

So, $b' = P_Ab$. And, if you put this into formula (1), you get

$$
Ax = A(A^tA)^{-1}A^tb \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad A^tAx = A^tA(A^tA)^{-1}A^tb = A^tb \ .
$$

That is, formula (2).

Comment: How does the system $Ax=b'$ becomes $A^tAx=A^{t}b$?

Comment: @jscherman See my edit.

Comment: I know it is an old post, but what is the explanation for the deficient rank case of the overdetermined LLS problem?

Answer (score 5):

Assume there is an exact solution $\small A \cdot x_s = b $ and reformulate your problem as $\small A \cdot x = b + e $ where *e* is an error ( thus $\small A \cdot x = b  $ is then only an approximation as required) we have then that $\small A \cdot (x_s - x) = e $

Clearly there are arbitrary/infinitely many solutions for *x* possible, or say it even more clear: you may fill in any values you want into *x* and always get some *e*. The *least-squares* idea is to find that *x* such that the sum of squares of components in *e* ( define $\small \operatorname{ssq}(e) = \sum_{k=1}^n e_k^2 $) is minimal. But if our data are all real data (what is usually assumed) then the smallest possible sum of squares of numbers is zero, so there in fact exists an effective minimum for the sum.
Then restrictions on *x* may cause, that actually the error *ssq(e)* is bigger but always there will be a minimum $\small \operatorname{ssq}(e) \ge 0 $.

So the question is answered in the affirmative.

(A remaining question is, whether it is unique, but that was not in your original post.)

Answer (score 4):

We just need to prove that the rank of matrix $A^TA$ equals the rank of augmented matrix $[A^TA,A^Tb]$. We prove it below:

denote the rank of matrix as rank A=k. By using the rank equality(can be found in nearly every algebra textbook.):rank $A^TA$=rank $A$=rank $A^T$. We know rank $[A^TA,A^Tb]\ge$rank A, since the former has one more column than the latter. But, on the other hand, $[A^TA,A^Tb]=A^T[A,b]$, and by using the rank inequality(can be found in some algebra textbooks):
rank $AB\le$ min{rank A, rank B}. so rank $A^T[A,b]$$\le$rank $A^T$=rank A=k.
Combining the two inequality, we have rank $[A^TA,A^Tb]$=k.

So the rank of matrix$[A^TA]$ is always equal to the rank of the augmented matrix$[A^TA,A^Tb]$. By the theorem of existence and uniqueness of vector equation, we know the least square problem always has at least one solution. Thus we finish our proof. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1):

**Trivial solution only **

There is only a trivial solution when $b \in\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A}^{*})$.

In essence, the method of least squares find the projection of the data vector $b$ onto $\mathcal{R}(\mathbf{A})$. When the data vector lives in the null space, there is no projection onto the range.

$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} x & = b \\
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0
\end{array} \right]
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  x_{1} \\
  x_{2} \\
\end{array} \right]
&=
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  0 \\
  0 \\
  1
\end{array} \right]
\end{align}
$$

[image: Projection]

Comment: Please, could you tell me how you generated that image? I really like the shadows.

Comment: @Guillermo Mosse: Mathematica. ¿Tiene el programa Mathematica?

Comment: I can get it. Thanks!

Comment: @Guillermo Mosse: send an email (see profile) and I can send the script.

Comment: Don't you think the projection still exists in your case and it's just $\overrightarrow{0}$? So, in this case you're just solving the homogeneous system $Ax = 0$. And a homogeneous linear system always has a solution: $x =0$. Does it matter if the solution is trivial?

Comment: @d.t.: This is a confusing point; thanks for providing a sharp question. (1) By convention, 0 solutions are excluded to prevent the tedium of adding "+0" to every linear system solution. (2) Perhaps this example will help: [Addendum: Existence of the Least Squares Solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878383/find-the-least-squares-solution-for-rank-deficient-system/1878397?noredirect=1#comment6228825_1878397).

Comment: @dantopa I think there is no confusion at all. If you look into any linear algebra book, and check the definition of orthogonal projection, you'll see that, in case your vector $b$ projects to the zero vector..., well it projects to the zero vector: $\overrightarrow{0}$ is a legit vector in every vector space. Also, there is no such convention to exclude $\overrightarrow{0}$ as a legit solution of a system of linear equations. Not in any linear algebra book I am aware of, and I know quite a few. But I would appreciate very much that you can find such a book with such a convention.

Answer (score 0):

To see that a solution always exists, recall that the definition of a least-squares solution is one that minimizes $\|Ax-b\|_2$. To get *the* solution, you'd use something like the pseudoinverse on paper or some nice minimization algorithm in practice. We don't even need to refer to the rank of the matrix or anything like that to assertain the existance of a solution. Minimizing $\|Ax-b\|_2$ in $x$ amounts to minimimizing a nonnegative quadratic equation in $n$ variables (the $x_i$'s). Simple calculus alone justifies the existence of a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$$\displaystyle{A^{\dagger}Ax = A^{\dagger}b}$ is equivalent to minimize
$\displaystyle{\left(Ax - b\right)^{2}}$.

$\large{\sf Example}:$
$2x = 5$ and $3x = 7$ becomes
$$
{2 \choose 3}\pars{x} = {5 \choose 7}
\quad\imp\quad
\pars{2 \quad 3}{2 \choose 3}\pars{x} = \pars{2 \quad 3}{5 \choose 7}
\quad\imp\quad
\pars{13}\pars{x} = \pars{31}
$$

$$
x = {31 \over 13}
$$
which is the minimum of the function $\pars{2x - 5}^{2} + \pars{3x - 7}^{2}$.

Answer (score -1):

I do not think it is true because solving finding a least squares solution amounts to solving A^{T}Ax=A^{T}b, and that A^{T}A might not always be invertible. If A^{T}A  is not invertible it follows, from the invertible matrix theorem, that the transformation it represents is neither onto nor one-to-one  .

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The whole point of least squares is that in the case that $A$ (or $A^TA$) is not invertible you get a solution which minimizes $\|Ax-b\|_2$. The pseudoinverse is precisely what gives the minimizer and it always exists.

Comment: I was just talking about finding a least squares solution by solving A^{T}Ax=A^{T}b. 

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253692/least-squares-method/372803#372803