# Find the least squares solution for rank deficient system

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, least-squares

> Find the least squares solution to the system
>
> $$x - y = 4$$
>
> $$x - y = 6$$

Normally if I knew what the matrix $A$ was and what $b$ was I could just do $(A^TA)^{-1} A^Tb$, but in this case I'm not sure how to set up my matrices. How can I find the least square solution to the system?

Answer (score 4):

**Problem statement: underdetermined system**

Start with the linear system
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} x &= b \\
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & -1 \\
 1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 x \\
 y
\end{array}
\right]
%
&=
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 4 \\
 6
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$

The system has matrix rank $\rho = 1$; therefore, if a solution exists, it will not be unique.

Provided $b\notin \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}$, we are guaranteed a least squares solution
$$
  x_{LS} = \left\{ x\in\mathbb{C}^{2} \colon \lVert \mathbf{A} x_{LS} - b \rVert_{2}^{2} \text{ is minimized} \right\}
\tag{1}
$$

**Subspace resolution**

By inspection, we see that the row space is resolved as
$$
\color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} 
=
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
 -1
\end{array}
\right]} \oplus
    \color{red}{\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  1 \\
  1
\end{array}
\right]} 
$$
The column space is resolved as
$$
\color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} 
=
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{c}
  1 \\
  1
\end{array}
\right]} \oplus
    \color{red}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  -1 \\
   1
\end{array}
\right]} 
$$

The coloring indicates vectors in the $\color{blue}{range}$ space and the $\color{red}{null}$ space.

**Finding the least squares solution**

Since there is only one vector in $\color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}$, the solution vector will have the form
$$
 \color{blue}{x_{LS}} = \alpha 
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
 -1
\end{array}
\right]}
$$
The goal is to find the constant $\alpha$ to minimize (1):
$$
 \color{red}{r}^{2} = \color{red}{r} \cdot \color{red}{r} = 
\lVert
 \color{blue}{\mathbf{A} x_{LS}} - b
\rVert_{2}^{2}
=
8 \alpha ^2-40 \alpha +52
$$
The minimum of the polynomial is at 
$$
 \alpha = \frac{5}{2}
$$

**Least squares solution**

The set of least squares minimizers in (1) is then the affine set given by
$$ 
 x_{LS} = \frac{5}{2}
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
 -1
\end{array}
\right]}
+
\xi
\color{red}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
  1
\end{array}
\right]}, \qquad \xi\in\mathbb{C}
$$

The plot below shows how the total error $\lVert \mathbf{A} x_{LS} - b \rVert_{2}^{2}$ varies with the fit parameters. The blue dot is the particular solution, the dashed line homogeneous solution as well as the $0$ contour - the exact solution.

**Addendum: Existence of the Least Squares Solution**

To address the insightful question of @RodrigodeAzevedo, consider the linear system:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} x &= b \\
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 x \\
 y
\end{array}
\right]
%
&=
%
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 1
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
$$

The data vector $b$ is entirely in the null space of $\mathbf{A}^{*}$: 
$b\in \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}$

As pointed out, the system matrix has the singular value decomposition. One instance is:
$$\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{U}\, \Sigma\, \mathbf{V}^{*} = \mathbf{I}_{2} 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\mathbf{I}_{2}$$
and the concomitant pseudoinverse,
$$\mathbf{A}^{\dagger} = \mathbf{V}\, \Sigma^{\dagger} \mathbf{U}^{*} = 
\mathbf{I}_{2}
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\mathbf{I}_{2} = \mathbf{A}$$

Following least squares canon, the particular solution to the least squares problem is computed as
$$
\color{blue}{x_{LS}} = \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} b =
\color{red}{\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]}
\qquad \Rightarrow\Leftarrow
$$
The color collision (null space [red] = range space [blue]) indicates a problem. There is no component of a particular solution vector in a range space!

Mathematicians habitually exclude the $0$ vector a solution to linear problems.

Comment: If the RHS of the normal equations is zero, there will be infinitely many solutions when $\bf A$ does not have full column rank. Lastly, I do not understand your hostility towards the zero solution.

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo: Here is a picture in 3D: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2253443/difference-between-least-squares-and-minimum-norm-solution/2253614#2253614. The least squares solution $$
 x_{LS} = 
\color{blue}{\mathbf{A}^{+} b} +
\color{red}{ 
\left(
\mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{+} \mathbf{A}
\right) y}, \quad y \in \mathbb{C}^{n}
\tag{1}
$$ The topology of the particular solution is a point (finite), and the homogeneous solution is a hyperplane. The pseudoinverse solution is where the homogenous solution intersects the range space. There is no intersection here.

Comment: Why even bring the pseudoinverse to the discussion?

Comment: The pseudoinverse provides the most general form of the particular solution (the range space component).

Answer (score 2):

The linear system

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1\\ 1 & -1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 6\end{bmatrix}$$

has no solution. Left-multiplying both sides by $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1\\ 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}^T$, we obtain the **normal equations**

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -2\\ -2 & 2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 10 \\ -10\end{bmatrix}$$

Dividing both sides by $2$ and removing the redundant equation,

$$x - y = 5$$

Thus, there are infinitely many **least-squares** solutions. One of them is

$$\begin{bmatrix} \hat x\\ \hat y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 6\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

The least-squares solution is a solution to the normal equations, **not** to the original linear system.

Answer (score 2):

First, choose points (x,y) that satisfy each equation.

$\begin{cases}
x - y = 4,  & \text{(6,2)} \\
x - y = 6, & \text{(10,4)}
\end{cases}$

Then, proceed as usual

$Ax = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 6 \\
1 & 10 \\
\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}
b \\
m \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
4 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}
b \\
m \\
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
5 \\
1/2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$y = 1/2x + 5$

Answer (score -1):

Your matrix is just the coefficients of your system of equations.  In this case 
$$ x-y = 4  $$
$$ x-y = 6  $$
leads to 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\ 1 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
4 \\ 6
\end{bmatrix}
$$
but you should see that there is no solution to this since you can't have $x-y$ be both $4$ and $6$...

Comment: The OP is looking for the least-squares solution, which always exist.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo What would it be in this case, and is it unique?  Yes maybe you can identify a LS solution, but what would the meaning of it be here with only two points?  The OP's suggestion of inv(A'*A)*A'*b results in [NaN;NaN] according to MATLAB.

Comment: @Carser it's not necessary for the system to have a solution. This is the essence of least squares.  Find the $(x,y)$  that minimises the distance between the vectors  $(1,1)'x +(-1,-1)'y$ and $(4,6)$

Comment: @theoGR You are of course correct, you can find a LS fitting here, but what is it worth when there are only two datum and a singular matrix?

Comment: Although this is a simple example, often we   have what is  caIled  collinearity effects and the matrix is singular.  In that case the LS solution  exists but is not  unique.

Comment: I've unmarked the answer as @Carser is incorrect. There is definitely a LS solution which is what I asked

Comment: @Yusha, I'd just ask what I ask above: what is the solution?  There are answers below that agree there is not just one single LS solution to this system.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. No one ever gave a correct answer.

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo: There is no (non-trivial) least squares solution when the data vector s in the null space. See, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244851/exact-solution-of-overdetermined-linear-system/2261603#2261603

Comment: @dantopa SVD tells me there is always a least-squares solution. One of us is making unwarranted assumptions.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Excellent observation. This issue warranted an addendum to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

We have the linear system

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1\\ 1 & -1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x\\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 6\end{bmatrix}$$

which can be rewritten in the form

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix} \eta = \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 6\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\eta = x - y$. Left-multiplying both sides by $\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}^\top$, we obtain $2 \eta = 10$, or, $\eta = 5$. Hence,

$$x - y = 5$$

Thus, there are infinitely many **least-squares** solutions. One of them is

$$\begin{bmatrix} \hat x\\ \hat y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 6\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$