# Computing a least-squares least-norm solution to image deconvolution

Tags: linear-algebra, convolution, signal-processing, inverse-problems, deconvolution

I want to deconvolve an image $h$ by a kernel $f$. More precisely, let

$$G = \operatorname*{argmin}_g \|f \ast g - h\|_2$$

be the set of least-squares solutions. I want to find the least-norm solution in this set:

$$ \hat{g} \in \operatorname*{argmin}_{g \in G} \|g\|_2 $$

[which is](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2253614/76284)

$$ \hat{g} = (f \mathrel{\ast})^+ h $$

where $^+$ is the [pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) and $f \mathrel{\ast}$ is the [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) constructed from $f$.

What algorithm can efficiently compute $\hat{g}$, particularly in the setting of 2D images? [Richardson–Lucy deconvolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%E2%80%93Lucy_deconvolution) doesn't work because I get division-by-zero errors (e.g. when $f$ is the [discrete Laplace operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator#Implementation_via_operator_discretization)). Are there other, possibly gradient-based, iterative methods that don't suffer from this problem?