# Computing least square solution when eigenvalue and eigenvectors are known.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose a matrix $A$ has eigenvalues 0, 3, 7 and eigenvectors $\mathbf{u, v, w,}$ respectively. Find the least square minimum length solution for $A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{u+v+w}$.

This was on our engineering math final exam last year and we've tried some techniques about Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, which didn't seem to work. Can someone help?

Comment: What size is $A $?

Comment: A is 3 by 3 matrix. All of eigenvalues and eigenvectors of A is known as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that there is no such vector $x$ that satisfies
$$
Ax = u+v+w.$$ We can see this easily from the fact that
$$\operatorname{ran} A =\operatorname{span}\{v,w\}.$$

$\textbf{EDIT:}$ Our problem can be written as follows. First, find $y \in \operatorname{ran}A$ (that is, $y=Ax$ for some $x$)
such that
$$
\lVert y-(u+v+w)\rVert \leq \lVert z-(u+v+w)\rVert,\quad\forall z\in\operatorname{ran}A.
$$ Then find $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $Ax=y$ and
$$
\lVert x\rVert\leq \lVert x'\rVert, \quad\forall x':Ax'=y.
$$

Firstly, the solution $y$ is given by the orthogonal projection $P(u+v+w)$ of $u+v+w$ onto $\operatorname{ran} A$. What we need to do is to compute $Pu$ since $P(v+w) = v+w$. To do this, let
$$
Pu = \alpha v +\beta w.$$ It should be that
$$
u-Pu = u-(\alpha v +\beta w) \perp v,w.
$$ This gives a system of equations about $\alpha,\beta$:
$$
\langle u,v\rangle=\alpha \langle v,v \rangle +\beta \langle w,v \rangle,
$$ and
$$
\langle u,w\rangle= \alpha\langle v,w \rangle+ \langle w,w \rangle.
$$ (If $A$ is normal, then we have $\langle u,v\rangle=\langle v,w\rangle=\langle w,v\rangle=0$. But this is not true in general.)

Solving this equation gives $y =(\alpha+1)v + (\beta+1)w$. Finally, note that
$$
A^{-1}(\{y\}) = \{\frac{(\alpha+1)}{3}v+\frac{(\beta+1)}{7}w+\gamma u\;|\;\gamma\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$
 To minimize  $\lVert x \rVert$ over $x\in A^{-1}(\{y\})$, it must be that
$$
x =\frac{(\alpha+1)}{3}v+\frac{(\beta+1)}{7}w+\gamma u \perp u.
$$
This gives us
$$
x = \frac{(\alpha+1)}{3}\left(v-\frac{\langle v,u\rangle}{\lVert u \rVert^2}u\right) + \frac{(\beta+1)}{7}\left(w-\frac{\langle w,u\rangle}{\lVert u \rVert^2}u\right).
$$

Comment: From the fact that eigenvalue is zero, this seems trivial. How should I use this fact to compute least square solution?

Comment: I meant there is no solution of $Ax = u+v+w$. Perhaps I'm missing something. What is your definition of least squre solution?

Comment: least square is defined as a vector $x$ such that $|Ax-b|$ is minimized, as I know.

Comment: So basically what I know is that I have to find x which minimizes $||Ax-(u+v+w)||$ from given conditions. Additionally, if we have more than one solution as a least square solution, we should find out which one has minimum length. Formally, $||x||$ should be also minimized. 

Some of my friends are insisting that solution must be v/3+w/7, but we couldn't prove it.

Btw, thanks for your concern :)

Comment: So the minimization is two-folded. I think I can help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll study through this :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the basis made up of the eigenvectors, say $B$. Then use the fact that $A$ is diagonisable. Then you can appky least squares formula to  $D[x]_B=[Ax]_B=[1 \ 1 \ 1]^T$.

Comment: Thanks for a lesson. However, I still don't really get how am I supposed to apply least squares formula to $PD[x]_B$ after we changed basis to $u,v,w$. 
Would you mind elaborating a bit more? It would be very helpful.

Comment: @Gratus See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72222/existence-of-least-squares-solution-to-ax-b

Comment: In this case, it seems $A^T A$ is not invertible. Though I think I got your key idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$Ax$ owns to the set $E$ generated by $v$ and $w$.

Let us call $u_0$ the projection of $u$ on $E$.

Then $u =u_0+u_1$ with $u_1$ orthogonal to $E$.

The best you can obtain is $Ax = u_0 + v + w$, projection theorem.
As $u_0$ owns to $E$, it can be represented as $u_0 =\alpha v + \beta w$, and one solution is
$$ x = \frac{1+\alpha}{3}v + \frac{1+\beta}{7}w $$

This simple solution minimizes the error on the output.

Comment: Can this solution written in forms of $v$ and $w$? 
Some of my friends are insisting that solution must be $\mathbf{v}/3+\mathbf{w}/7$, but we couldn't prove it.

Comment: I will try to complete it later